# HTML Colour bootstrap picker issue

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Could somebody please explain what I'm doing incorrectly?

I'm using bootstrap3, I'm currently using the following code for a colour palette picker which gathers hex colour from a database. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuTTf.png

```html
  <input type="color" name="color" value="<?php echo $result['color']?>"></br>
```

Which works fine i just don't like the look of the standard pallette design.

So i'm trying to use

```html
<input id="color" type="color" value="<?php echo $result['color']?>" class="form-control" />
```

Which looks like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYner.png

What am i doing wrong?

```html
<div class="form-group">
                <input id="color" type="color" value="&lt?php echo $result['color']?&gt" class="form-control" /> </br>
  </div>
```

didn't help.

Comment: Wrap it with <div class="form-group"></div>

Comment: <div class="form-group">
       <input id="color" type="color" value="<?php echo $result['servicecolour']?>" class="form-control" />

    </div> doesn't store the colour in the database.

Comment: where as  the below does.

 <div class="form-group">
              Select your service nav colour:
                            <input type="color" name="servicecolour" value="<?php echo $result['servicecolour']?>"></br>
                          </div>

Comment: You can move the class attribute before the value one, but I think you just need to escape the "<" and ">" inside the attribute value. Use &lt and &gt. I think that the class attribute that comes after the value being ignored..

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="form-group">
       <input id="color" type="color" value="<?php echo $result['color']?>" class="form-control" />

    </div>
```

Isn't storing the colour in the database where as this works.

```html
<div class="form-group">
              Select your service nav colour:
                            <input type="color" name="color" value="<?php echo $result['color']?>"></br>
                          </div>
```

But it is the wrong style as i want the bootstrap version.

Comment: Edit your own question. Don't use answers to comment or edit your question :)